# Android Room Database VIewModel is not reflecting latest Inserted Data?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am a beginner in Android Development. So please help me to find out solution to my problem.

I am making Music app as practice project. As user search for an artist, API fetches results and results get stored in room database. I want to display results stored in room through ViewModel. But ViewModel is not showing results synchronously as data is inserted. At first search, it shows nothing. But after subsequent searches, it displays results.

Api call and insert data in Room.

```
        artistResultsCallback.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseModel>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseModel>, response: Response<ResponseModel>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful) {
                    hideProgressBar()
                   artistRepository.insertList(response.body()!!.getArtistModel()!!)
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseModel>, t: Throwable) {
                hideProgressBar()
                Log.e("MainActivity","An error occurred")

            }


        })
```

my dao

```
@Dao
interface ArtistDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertArtists(artistList:List<Artist>)


@Query("SELECT * FROM Artists WHERE artistName LIKE :name")
fun getArtists(name:String):LiveData<List<Artist>>

@Query("DELETE FROM Artists")
fun deleteArtists()


}
```

my ViewModel

```
class ArtistViewModel(): ViewModel() {

fun getArtists(application: Application,name:String):LiveData<List<Artist>>{
      var artistRepository =ArtistRepository(application)

  var artistResults:LiveData<List<Artist>> = artistRepository.getResultsList(name)
  return  artistResults


}

}
```

my database

```
    @Database(entities = [Artist::class],version = 3)
    abstract class ArtistDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun artistDao(): ArtistDao

     companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var artistDb: ArtistDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabaseInstance(context: Context): ArtistDatabase {

        return artistDb ?: synchronized(this) {
            artistDb ?: Room.databaseBuilder(context, ArtistDatabase::class.java, Constants.ARTIST_DATABASE).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
        }

    }


}


}
```

My repository:

```
class ArtistRepository(application: Application) {

private var artistDao: ArtistDao?

init {
    val artistDb= ArtistDatabase.getDatabaseInstance(application)
    artistDao= artistDb.artistDao()
}

fun getResultsList(name:String):LiveData<List<Artist>>{
      return artistDao!!.getArtists(name)
}

fun insertList(artist:List<Artist>){
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
          artistDao!!.deleteArtists()
          artistDao!!.insertArtists(artist)
      }
}

}
```

Activity showing results

```
    artistRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_artist)

    var getIntent = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.ARTIST_NAME)


    search_results_for.text="Search Results for: $getIntent"

           artistViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ArtistViewModel::class.java)

           var artistViewModelResults:LiveData<List<Artist>> = artistViewModel.getArtists(application,getIntent!!)


           artistViewModelResults.observe(this, object:Observer<List<Artist>>{
               override fun onChanged(t: List<Artist>) {
                  setUpUi(t)
               }
           })
```